# How to obtain evenly sized faces throughout the model?

Tags: faces

I created the following shape and I'm trying to find a way to make all of the faces even squares. 
I tried Looptools -> Space which distorts completely the model. The Remesh modifier doesn't seem to do any good either. Could someone help me with this?

[image: Front view]

[image: Side view]

Comment: Oh and don't mind the little triangles, I forgot to delete those.

Comment: Regular polyhedron for a square face list only a Cube.  Is this a math question?
Are your requirements for same square face size strict?
What about connectivity and smoothness?  
Does connectivity mean hinged on two adjacent corners?
Blender modeling is usually polygon placement.  

Polygon Zig Zag and Spiral seem to work for planes and strips while connected.
This includes a polygon cylinder.  
Blender has no built in object for a sphere composed of square polygons other than the cube.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was wondering if it is even possible to make each of the faces more or less the same size and close to a square without losing the smoothness. Now when I think of it, the shape would probably get deformed in the process.

Comment: If you allow just a little wiggle room for connectivity, angle and size then you will be able to get more final shapes. Of course the open weave helps if you do not inspect negative space too much.  I suggest particle systems, armatures on objects or slight twist on your work over larger distances.

Comment: Great, this gives me options to try. Thank you